# SignalR access hub from elsewhere in server

Tags: iis, signalr

I'm hosting SignalR in IIS along with my application and while my remote clients can connect happily I can't get my application which has created the hubs to connect and take part itself reliably.

I have tried to connect to the hub from within the web server process which is successful but only if I know what port it is hosted on.  As that can be configured from IIS to be anything then I don't know what port to try to connect to internally.

I had hoped I could make use of the IHubContext but that only seems to give me ways of sending messages but not receiving them.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

-- Edit --

I've moved on with my experimenting but I've hit a different brick wall now.

I'm setting up my hub like this

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(StatusHub), () => this.StatusHub);
```

So that I can have a single instance of the hub and hook into events on it from within my server but external to the hub itself.

I can then make use of a couple of events

```
public event EventHandler<string> Connected;

public event EventHandler<string> Disconnected;
```

And then else where

```
this.statusHub.Connected += (sender, connectionId) => this.UpdateServerStatus(connectionId);
this.statusHub.Disconnected += (sender, connectionId) => this.ReleaseLicense(connectionId);
```

And these functions get called as clients connect and disconnect when the hub makes the overidden calls to

```
public override Task OnConnected()
```

and

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
```

What I then can't seem to do is actually send messages to the clients using the hub.  I've tried to do this

```
var host = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatusHub>();
host.Clients.All.Update(args);
```

and while host comes back as a valid object no client function I call on it appears to get through and I can't see any clients on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was missing a key point.  I'm no longer connecting to my own hub internally because the callbacks call me when I need to know.

Calling the client function in the end I was trying to call a hub function Update() and not the client function heartbeat().